# How can we achieve mTLS implementation for a mobile app (iOS/Android) with react native and apollo client for hitting APIs?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I have graphql apis at the backend and apollo client implemented in react-native. I am trying to implement mTLS so that I can pass a cert while sending a request to the apis. However, I could not find any resource on Apollo Graphql docs (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking). I would really appreciate if someone can point me into right direction to implement mTLS for a mobile app with react native and apollo client in it. Thank you!

Comment: Nope, no luck yet. I feel, Apollo Client doesn't support it yet.

Comment: I searched a bit more after leaving the above comment and I guess `certificate pinning` might be the thing we need. Still need to explore it though.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I am also exploring cert pinning with this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cert-pinner. Let's see how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried the solution yet, however, refer this link where I asked the same question - https://community.apollographql.com/t/how-to-implement-mtls-with-apolloclient-in-reactnative/5883 . I will add the solution once I tried it. Thanks!